# Accelerometer Sensor Output Impedance

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, sensor, impedance

I am looking into purchasing a [TE 810M1 Accelerometer](https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=srchrtrv&DocNm=810M1_Accelerometer&DocType=Data%20Sheet&DocLang=English) and had a question regarding the resistor's value for amplifying the sensors output. Here is a photo of the sensors electrical properties: 
[image]

The output impedance is a property of the sensor and can not be changed, correct? Thus when selecting the resistor value for the op amp, should I select the impedance to be less than 100 Ohms or should I select a value where the current into the OpAmp circuit is less than 22uA? I'm siding with selecting the larger resistor value to be safe and avoid burning the sensor.

Comment: Are you under the impression that your signal conditioner needs to be an impedance match to the sensor?  That is incorrect.

Comment: no im worried about the current output of the sensor and do not want to have too low of impedance where the current is higher than the sensor can output

Comment: As mentioned, you want a good high input impedance to your amplifier.  Satisfy that, and your current consumption will take care of itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to accurately work with the sensor output, at the 0.1% accuracy level, then the Rin of the "amplifier" needs to be at least 100 ohm/0.1% , or at least 100,000 Ohm.

A circuit like this is a good start

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpWIxD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you explain the 0.1% accuracy level and where this value comes from?

Comment: I figured a 0.1% accurate circuit might be adequate for your purposes. To achieve that, the OpAmp needs to have Rin of 100 ohm/0.1% or at least 100,000 ohms. In this non-inverting circuit, pretty much **ANY** opamp will provide Rin >> 100,000 ohms.

Comment: I'm actually using an inverting op amp to remove the offset on the signal that I am removing so the signal can be in range of my ADC. I went with inverting as I have about 9 signals it's fewer components to fit on a small PCB and it's not a big deal if it's inverted for my application. I read some more on the 0.1% accuracy circuit and will put a 100k ohm resistor for Rin and Rf(gain of 1). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> The output impedance is a property of the sensor and can not be changed, correct?

You're correct.  The output impedance of the sensor can't be changed.  It may be that the output stage of the sensor is an OpAmp, so the maximum output impedance of the sensor is derived from the maximum output impedance of that OpAmp.

> ...when selecting the resistor value for the op amp, should I select the impedance to be less than 100 ohms or should I select a value where the current into the OpAmp circuit is less than 22uA?

Choose the resistors in the OpAmp circuit to maximize the OpAmp circuit's input impedance.

The [datasheet for TE 810M1 is awfully  brief](https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=srchrtrv&DocNm=810M1_Accelerometer&DocType=Data%20Sheet&DocLang=English).  It doesn't specify the max current which the output can drive.  22μA seems like a small value for max output current.  I suspect that the max output current is larger, on the order of units of mA.  (For a comparison, a [jellybean OpAmp](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/MCP601) can output around 10mA.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I wished there was more information on the datasheet and TE connectivity isnt the best at responding to questions. Thanks for your help. I chose the 22uA number just because that is the current input in the sensor and assumed that if the current output is less than that value or near it I minimize the chances of damaging the sensor regardless of the internal circuit. I will select a large resistor to put onto the output of sensor and may follow analogsystmsrf advice based on his response to a follow up question. Thanks again